# Output a pair of objects with stream

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`, where `Foo` has a list of `Bar`s in its attributes. Something like this:

```java
public class Bar {
   int id;
   ...

   public boolean isGood() {...}
}
```

```java
public class Foo {
   int id;
   List<Bar> bars;
   ...
    public boolean hasBadBar() {
        boolean hasOnlyGoodBars = bars.stream().allMatch(Bar::isGood);
        return !hasOnlyGoodBars;
    }
}
```

Now imagine I have a list of `Foo`s called `foos` and want to go through `foos` and report `Foo`s that have `Bar`s that are bad (`bar.isGood()` is false). I want to report the pair of (String version of Foo `id`, String version of Bar `id`) of such incidents. Any ideas on how to do it in line with `stream()`?

I can report `id`s of such Foos (or such Bars) separately but I don't know how to do a pair of them.

Comment: What if multiple `Bar` s of a `Foo` are bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
List<Pair<Foo,Bar>> pairs = foos.stream().
            flatMap(
                    //take all the non-good Bars and create a Pair together with its Foo
                    foo -> foo.bars.stream().
                           filter(Predicate.not(Bar::isGood)).
                           map(bar -> new Pair(foo, bar))
            ).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `Pair` is some `class Pair<A,B>`

EDIT:
To get a `List<Pair<String,String>>` that holds their `id`s,

- either use Holger's approach from the comments:

  `new Pair<>(String.valueOf(foo.id), String.valueOf(bar.id))`
- or, if you need this list and the list of `id` pairs, transform the existing `List<Pair<Foo,Bar>> pairs` like this:

```
List<Pair<String,String>> idPairs = pairs.stream()
   .map(p -> new Pair<>(String.valueOf(p.getLeft().id),
                       String.valueOf(p.getRight().id)))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! Can you also please show I can get id's of such foos and bars and convert them in Strings? I know how to do it in a separate Streamapplied on `pairs` but want to learn how to do them nested in one line. The reason that I'm asking is that I'm using this inside a `joiner.on().join(....)` (from `com.google.common.base.Joiner`).

Comment: @Mahdibelly to get id strings instead, just replace `new Pair<>(foo, bar)` with `new Pair<>(String.valueOf(foo.id), String.valueOf(bar.id))` and the result type to `List<Pair<String,String>>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 1) you only cared about the first bad bar, and 2) you added an Optional firstBadBar() method to Foo, this code would work to collect the ids into a map:

```
Map<String,String> result = foos.stream()
        .filter( foo -> foo.firstBadBar().isPresent() )
        .collect( Collectors.toMap( foo -> String.valueOf( foo.id ), foo -> String.valueOf( foo.firstBadBar().get().id ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

since you need to return a list of lists you may want to use flatMap to collect everything

```
List<Pair> fooBarPair = foos.stream().flatMap( foo -> {
            List<Bar> badBars = foo.getBadBars();
            return badBars.stream().map( bar -> new Pair( foo.toString(), bar.toString() ) );
        } ).toList();
```

```
public class Test {
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString(exclude = "isGood")
    static class Bar {
        int id;
        boolean isGood;

        public boolean isGood() {return isGood;}
        public boolean isBad() {return !isGood;}
    }


    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString(exclude = "bars")
    @Getter
    public class Foo {
        int id;
        List<Bar> bars;
        public boolean hasBadBar() {
            return bars.stream().filter(Bar::isBad).toList().size() != bars.size();
        }
        public List<Bar> getBadBars() {
            return bars.stream().filter( Bar::isBad ).collect( Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    static class Pair {
        String foo;
        String bar;
    }

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void test() {
        List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Bar> barsFoo0 = new ArrayList<>();
        barsFoo0.add( new Bar( 1, true ) );
        barsFoo0.add( new Bar( 2, true ) );
        barsFoo0.add( new Bar( 3, false ) );

        List<Bar> barsFoo1 = new ArrayList<>();
        barsFoo1.add( new Bar( 1, false ) );
        barsFoo1.add( new Bar( 2, false ) );
        barsFoo1.add( new Bar( 3, true ) );

        foos.add( new Foo( 0, barsFoo0 ) );
        foos.add( new Foo( 1, barsFoo1 ) );

        List<Pair> fooBarPair = foos.stream().flatMap( foo -> {
            List<Bar> badBars = foo.getBadBars();
            return badBars.stream().map( bar -> new Pair( foo.toString(), bar.toString() ) );
        } ).toList();

        System.out.println(fooBarPair);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work if no collecting required:

```
    foos.stream()
        .filter(f ->f.hasBadBars())
        .forEach(f -> {
            System.out.printf("Foo %d has bad bars:%n", f.getId());
            f.getBars().stream()
                .filter(b -> !b.getIsGood())
                .forEach(bad ->System.out.printf("\tId of bad Bar: %d%n", bad.getId()));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Map<Foo, List<Bar>>` (mapping a `Foo` to a `List<Bar>` containing all the bad `Bar`s associated with the `Foo`).

First, you have a `List<Foo> foos`.

Then, you can use `stream()`:

```java
Map<Foo, List<Bar>> result = foos.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.hasBadBar())
    .map(x -> {
         List<Bar> badBars = new ArrayList<>(x.bars);
         badBars.removeIf(bar -> bar.isGood());
         return new Pair<>(x, badBars);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
```

The `filter` method is used only to keep the `Foo` objects that have bad `Bar`s, then the `map` method is used to create `Pair<Foo, List<Bar>>` objects for each `Foo` object, with the original `Foo` object as the key, and a list of bad `Bar`s as the value. Finally, the `collect` method is used to collect the elements of the stream into a `Map`.

Then, you can use the `Map` to print a `Foo` and all the corresponding bad `Bar`s